# Text opacity on scroll

Tags: javascript, java, scroll, opacity

I'm trying to make the text fade as I scroll down, but there is something wrong with the javascript. I have searched through the site, but not found anything suitable. Other codes either don't work or work by adding a colour gradient.

To clarify, I want the opacity to alter on scroll.

Any help would be much apprciated.
Thanks

```js
function scrollh3() {
  $(document).scroll(function(){
      var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
      $('h3').css({
        'top' : (scrollPos/4)-'px',
        'opacity' : 1-(scrollPos/100)
      });
      $('#').css({
        'background-position' : 'center ' + (-scrollPos/3)+'px'
      });
  });    
}
scrollh3();
```

```css
h3 {
    margin: 0 auto;
  height: 1000px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    padding: 5% 10% 10% 10%;   
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #000000;  
    
}
```

```html
                    <h3>About<br><br><br>
                
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tellus risus, vestibulum non neque ut, consectetur fermentum neque. Nam pharetra tellus pulvinar ante suscipit dapibus. Quisque pharetra libero vel lectus placerat laoreet. Aliquam et elit eu mauris volutpat ultricies vel pharetra libero. Vivamus egestas ante metus, vel ornare mi imperdiet ac. Nulla pharetra scelerisque tortor eget dictum. Donec tincidunt massa quis blandit maximus.
<br><br><br>Read More</h3>
```

Comment: Your code is jQuery, not vanilla javascript. If you actually load the jQuery library, your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/gkoderLf/

Comment: Read the introduction for javascript and jquery. Its not our job to tell you the difference between java and js

Comment: @Jonasw Never said it was. This is my first time using this website, but if the comminity is this unfriendly I think I'll leave. Cheers